# Why "requests.get()" opens "url.py" in Python 3.6.4?

Tags: python, python-requests

Beginner having trouble with "requests.get()" in python 3.6.4

Current setup: Visual Studio Code, Anaconda(Conda), conda env, Bash, and Git.

Running the following in a file 'crawl.py' in debug mode:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
text = r.text
print(text)
```

'url.py' opens automatically, telling me there is an error:

[image]

First failed attempts(I have to use --trusted-host because SSL_certificates are messed up):

$ pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -U requests

$ pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -U urllib3

---

I could use help to stop this error from happening and for it to simply

continue to print the the debug console.

I am thinking that the source of the error has to do with something like pylint

or maybe my version of Python. Because it also fails with "parse.py" when using "urlparse".

Feel free to recommend any free courses that might really be helpful to me as well.

Comment: I just tried the exact snippet you pasted, and it's working Ok [200] for me. It returned a object with a bunch of GitHub events. Could you please show us what's the error you're getting? Couldn't see it on the question.

Comment: Added to Carlos' request, can you also post the stacktrace that occurred just before the error. The code snippet seems to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation Carlos! It has to be my set up. There is no exact error because nothing shows up in the "PROBLEMS" section of the bash terminal. What happens is that the 'url.py' file opens up with the green arrow and green highlight, and the program stops running. It does not print out anything to  the "DEBUG CONSOLE" for me. I think it may have to do with the link between Visual Studio Code and Conda. It may be that when I use any kind of server-related url-finding code, VSC or Conda tries to do some kind of operation that's conflicting with my settings.

Comment: I found out that I had "stopOnEntry" set as 'true', so I changed that to 'false' and now the program fully runs through. This is the error it now throws: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)). Upon looking up this error, I believe the issue may have to deal with either the package 'pyopenssl' or something having to do with SSL Certificates. I'll start a new question.